# How to loop through two variables at once in r

Tags: r, loops, nested-loops

I am trying to loop through 2 variables together in R.

Here is what I have

```
for (x in c(gl_50, gl_100, gl_200,gl_300,gl_400,gl_500,gl_600, gl16)) {
     for (y in c(50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 670)) {
  gi_x <- gl2gi(x)
  sum_x <- basic.stats(gi_x)
  
  ind<-colMeans(sum_x$n.ind.samp, na.rm=T)
  Ho<-colMeans(sum_x$Ho, na.rm = T)
  Hs<-colMeans(sum_x$Hs, na.rm = T)
  Fis<-colMeans(sum_x$Fis, na.rm = T)

  sum<-data.frame(cbind(ind, Ho, Hs, Fis))
  sum$snp_no <- rep(y)
  print(sum)
```

The current result is the loop runs gl_50 with all values of y then gl_100 with all values of y and so on. What I want is gl_50 with 50, gl_100 with 100, gl_200 with 200 and so on.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Generally, you should loop through their indices and access them like:

```
a <- c(gl_50, gl_100, gl_200,gl_300,gl_400,gl_500,gl_600, gl16)
b <- c(50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 670)
for (i in seq_along(a)) {
  a[i] 
  b[i]  
}
```

Comment: That comment is difficult to read. Please format it and add it to your question. I do not have access to your data so this answer was made generally, but please read this about writing [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I changed parts of the loop with this. 'gi_x <- gl2gi(a[i]) and sum$snp_no <- rep(b[i])' It doesn't work. Have I got it wrong somewhere?

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer but I don't think this helps much with OPs (admittedly rather) diffuse question. More generally if the goal is to loop through entries of two objects/vectors "in parallel", `Map`/`mapply` (or `purrr::map`) is the R-like way to do that rather than using a `for` loop. If the goal is to process all combinations of elements from two vectors, `expand.grid` (or perhaps `outer`) would be the way forward. The bottom line is that vectorised operations are usually much faster in R than "classic" `for` loops.

Comment: First, I have to thank you for trying to help me with this. I tried your code by adding print(a[i]) and print(b[i]) and it works perfectly. However, I am working with a genlight object which holds multiple data slots. A part of my loop (basis.stats) pulls this data out. The error I got is at the reading a[i] in the first line. I got this error 'Error in gl2gi(a[i]) :  trying to get slot "other" from an object of a basic class ("list") with no slots'.

Comment: I found the problem. I just need a[[i]] instead of a[i]. Everything works now. Thank you so much @LMc for your patience with my question.